# SDWebimage exception at runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa, caching, sdwebimage

I´m using XCode 5.0 and i got this exception at runtime:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView
>   setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:]

I have download the **SDWebImage** from GitHub and:

- Imported the project **SDWebImage** to my project
- Imported **< SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>** to the header file
- Imported **ImageIO.framework**
- At **Build Settings** in **Other Linker Flags** i´ve put the **-ObjC** flag
- At **Build Phases** in **Target Dependencies** i´ve hadded **SDWebimage**
- At **Build Phases** in **Link Binary With Libraries** i´ve hadded **libSDWebImage.a**

The project is running without error but i get the exception above at this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in this line:

```
[cell.imageMeme setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:meme.linkImage]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row == 0 ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
```

Comment: What is `meme.linkImage`? Is it `NSString` or `NSURL` ?

Comment: Try without options - [cell.imageMeme setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:meme.linkImage]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre meme.linkImage is the link for the image that i want.

Comment: Whether it is `NSString` type or `NSURL` type?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre it is NSString

Comment: @rubr0 i get the same exception... Driving me crazy

Comment: Can you NSLog your `meme.linkImage` ?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Here it is: http://www.personal.psu.edu/ivs5030/plant.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the **SDWebImage** i had imported and imported only the folder **SDWebImage** with the .m and .h files. This way the project runs and it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: If your problem had solved, then accept your answer. It'll help others in future.